# My performSegueWithIdentifier method is not working when I try to logout of my app

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I'm getting an error that says "receiver has no segue with identifier 'showLogin'" when I try to logout of my app (I'm using Parse for my backend). I have checked the storyboard about 100 times now to make sure that the segue is there and that the spelling of "showLogin" is correct in both places. I've cleaned my build, deleted my app off of my phone, and restarted xcode, and it still doesn't seem to be working. I can't figure out why it won't work for my logout method, when the segue works in other parts of my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showLogin"])
    {
        [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
    }
}

- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender
{
    [PFUser logOut];
    [self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: So, there is a segue linked from the view controller icon (orange box) in this scene with the right name?  Just because it works elsewhere it doesn't mean that the segue is in *this* scene

Comment: Yes there is. I've tried using another segue located within the navigation controller, as well as linking a segue straight from this scene to the login viewcontroller that the showLogin identifier is supposed to segue to.

Comment: yes the segue is linked from the orange box.